# Error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable Using turtle graphics

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics

I am attempting to code space invaders. I am doing some finishing touches however when trying to create three hearts in the top corner to represent lives I have this error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

The relevant code in main.py is:

```
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
scoreboard = Scoreboard()
scoreboard.lives()
```

In the scoreboard file the relevant lines are:

```
class Scoreboard(Turtle):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.lives = []
    self.score = 0
    self.lives_start_x = 0
    with open("High_Score.txt") as data:
        self.high_score = int(data.read())
    self.color("white")
    self.penup()
    self.update_scoreboard()
    self.hideturtle()

def lives(self):
    heart = Turtle()
    heart.penup()
    heart.goto(x=self.lives_start_x, y=0)
    heart.color('white')
    heart.hideturtle()
    heart.pendown()
    d = 10
    r = d / math.tan(math.radians(67.5))
    heart.up()
    heart.seth(45)
    heart.begin_fill()
    heart.down()
    heart.fd(d)
    heart.circle(r, 225)
    heart.left(180)
    heart.circle(r, 225)
    heart.fd(d)
    heart.end_fill()
    self.lives.append(heart)
    self.lives_start_x += 35
```

Any ideas?

the code in the lives function also worked fine on a separate file on it's own while I was testing it.

Also I need to create a alien in turtle that actually look like an alien so any help with that would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: Your class is trying to use `lives` as the name of both an attribute and a method.  You're going to have to rename one of those uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `lives` list so that it does not replace the `lives` method.

For example, you could change it to `_lives`:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self._lives = []
    self.score = 0
    self.lives_start_x = 0
    with open("High_Score.txt") as data:
        self.high_score = int(data.read())
    self.color("white")
    self.penup()
    self.update_scoreboard()
    self.hideturtle()

def lives(self):
    heart = Turtle()
    heart.penup()
    heart.goto(x=self.lives_start_x, y=0)
    heart.color('white')
    heart.hideturtle()
    heart.pendown()
    d = 10
    r = d / math.tan(math.radians(67.5))
    heart.up()
    heart.seth(45)
    heart.begin_fill()
    heart.down()
    heart.fd(d)
    heart.circle(r, 225)
    heart.left(180)
    heart.circle(r, 225)
    heart.fd(d)
    heart.end_fill()
    self._lives.append(heart)
    self.lives_start_x += 35
```